# PHP - Debugging Require

Tags: php, debugging, require, require-once

I am having some problems using `require` or `require_once` in that the code halts execution after the call and I am struggling to find what exactly is causing the problem.

I have checked the file exists and can be read (via `file_exists` and `is_readable`) but both of these appear to be true so I am a little stumped.

```
require_once('file1.php');
print('a');
$file = 'file2.php';
if (!file_exists($file)) { die('file does not exist'); }
if (!is_readable($file)) { die('cannot read file'); }
require_once($file);
print('b');
```

Above code outputs only 'a' and nothing after.

Another file on the server uses both of the files in question in the same way without problem.

Is there anything else I could check?

Any help would be appreciated.

Edit:

Setting `error_reporting(E_ALL)` does not change the output.

Changing the file path to a blank file in the same directory changes the output to 'ab', indiciating the require has worked and suggesting their is a problem with `file2.php`, however another file on the server successfully uses these file in the exact same manner.

Running `php -l` for file2.php returns no errors.

Commenting out the first require makes no difference.

Edit2:

Problem was to do with a call to `class_exists` and the change in behaviour in version 5.0 to do with auto loading. The code in question was wrote before upgrade to 5.0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set `error_reporting(E_ALL)` and try to include an empty file instead of `file2.php`.

Maybe `file2.php` has some bug that halts the flow

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I have updated the question with what happens when I do both of the above. Changing error reporting doesn't seem to make a difference, changing path to an empty file works.. Another file on the server however uses this file successfully.

Comment: Maybe the other who uses that files set some var used by file2.php while you not

Comment: Doesn't seem to be the case, it works with the exact same code at the top of the file.

Comment: there are many other checks file2.php can do... like from where is executed and who required it... teh same code doesnt' mean anything

Comment: You are right, it is something in the file that is causing the problem. Commenting out the entire file allows it to work. Thanks for your help, I will update the question when I discover what exactly the problem is.

Comment: It's better to open a new question... don't mess everything :D Also take care to +1 and accept answer :D

Comment: I meant with the solution, not more questions, heh. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Maybe adding the semicolon at the end (`error_reporting(E_ALL);`) would help to avoid people running into the syntax error.

Answer (score 1):

There's probably an error somewhere in your `file2.php` file. You should enable error reporting:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

The error reporting level in case of failed `require_once` will be `E_COMPILE_ERROR`

**UPDATE**
Check whether `file1` and `file2` define functions with the same name, or have other incompatible logic.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but another file on the server uses file2 in the exact same way without problems which is a little confusing. file2.php also returns no errors when put through a PHP lint (php -l).

Comment: Thanks but that cannot be the case as another file (in a different directory) uses both file1 and file2 in the same way.

Comment: Also commenting out the first require makes no difference.